# Animating a filled rectangle with CoreAnimation

Tags: swift, core-animation

I am trying to animate a filled rectangle using CoreAnimation. When adding the animation to the `CAShapeLayer`, the animation is added, however, the animation looks strange.

I have attached gif:

[image: Example Animation]

I have created a small example:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TestView : UIView
{
    private var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        self.commonInit()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.commonInit()
    }

    fileprivate func commonInit()
    {
        self.progressLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

        let barWidth: CGFloat = self.frame.width * 0.33

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: self.bounds.width / 2 - barWidth / 2.0, y: self.bounds.height - 1.0, width: barWidth, height: 1.0), byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 6.0, height: 6.0))
        self.progressLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        self.progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        Swift.print(self.progressLayer.position)
        self.progressLayer.position = CGPoint(x: -barWidth / 2.0, y: 0.0)

        self.layer.addSublayer(self.progressLayer)
    }

    func animate()
    {
        let barWidth: CGFloat = self.frame.width * 0.33

        let from = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: self.bounds.width / 2 - barWidth / 2.0, y: self.bounds.height - 1.0, width: barWidth, height: 1.0), byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 6.0, height: 6.0))
        let to = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: self.bounds.width / 2 - barWidth / 2.0, y: 0.0, width: barWidth, height: self.bounds.height), byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 6.0, height: 6.0))

        // This works fine.
//        let from = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: self.bounds.width / 2 - barWidth / 2.0, y: self.bounds.height - 1.0, width: barWidth, height: 1.0))
//        let to = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: self.bounds.width / 2 - barWidth / 2.0, y: 0.0, width: barWidth, height: self.bounds.height))

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        animation.fromValue = from.cgPath
        animation.toValue = to.cgPath
        animation.duration = 0.8
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        self.progressLayer.add(animation, forKey: "path")
    }
}
```

When removing the rounded corners, everything works fine. How can I fix the animation so it only animates in one dimension (from bottom to top)?

Comment: Animating a CGPath is always risky. You have no idea what Cocoa believes is the way to portray one path turning into another (as your example clearly shows). Confine yourself to animating bounds and/or centers and/or transforms and you will be able to achieve predictable effects. So if the goal is to make the bar rise from bottom to top, then move the whole bar, itself, from bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto layout to do this:
declare your UIViews and your button under controller class:

```
let grayView = UIView()
let blueView = UIView()
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
```

in viewDidLoad set attributes and cal the function for constraints:

```
button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setTitle("Up", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleUp), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    grayView.backgroundColor = .gray
    grayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
    blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    setupConstraints()
```

now below viewDidLoad set variables for animation:

```
var normalHeight: NSLayoutConstraint?
var newHeight: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

after that write function to set constraints:

```
fileprivate func setupConstraints() {

    view.addSubview(grayView)
    grayView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    grayView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    grayView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
    grayView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true

    grayView.addSubview(blueView)
    blueView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: grayView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    blueView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: grayView.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: grayView.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    normalHeight = blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
    normalHeight?.isActive = true

    newHeight = blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: grayView.topAnchor)

    view.addSubview(button)
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: grayView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: grayView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: grayView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

last step write function to call animation and set corner radius:

```
@objc fileprivate func handleUp() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.normalHeight?.isActive = false
        self.newHeight?.isActive = true
        self.blueView.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        self.blueView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I posted a small example, but in fact the bar is part of a rather complex graph view. I really don't want to use constraints inside the view, I want to work with layers only. I think I will stroke the frame instead of filling it. I think I can get the rounded corners using an additional mask layer.